# getting "OAUTH_ERROR" while attempting login to Okta

Tags: angular, okta, okta-signin-widget

I have set up an angular app running on `http://localhost:4200` on my local server. I am using [Okta-signin-widget](https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget) as authentication.
When submitting the login form I get the following error in console:

```
error.errorCode: invalid_request, error.description: The 'redirect_uri' parameter 
must be an absolute URI that is whitelisted in the client app settings.
```

I googled but what I found was adding `http://localhost:4200` to the `API>Trusted Origins` in the Okta's Developer Console, but that did not help (it was already defined).

I have the following in my Okta applicaiton setting:

```
Login redirect URIs:              http://localhost:4200/implicit/callback   
                                  http://localhost:4200/urlform
```

and defined the redirect URI in the angular login code like this:

```
    this.widget.renderEl({
      el: '#okta-signin-container'},
      (res) => {
        if (res.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          this.signIn.loginRedirect('http://localhost:4200/urlform', { sessionToken: res.session.token });
          // Hide the widget
          this.widget.remove();
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        throw err;
      }
    );
```

But same problem. I am not sure if I am working on the right page.

Any ideas is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://localhost:4200` to the list of Login redirect URIs for your app and it should fix the problem.